# phppowerpoint pie chart exploding

Tags: php, powerpoint

I have a project in which data are show in pie chart. It can export the pie chart to powerpoint from php. But the pie chart is show with by exploding. I want to show it without exploding it. Is it possible?

I am using PowerPoint2007. And the code is as following -

```
  <?php
require_once 'iconnect.php';
require_once 'QueryHandler.php';
require_once 'ResultTypes.php';

include_once 'Sample_Header.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\PhpPowerpoint;
use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Shape\Chart\Type\Pie3D;
use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Style\Color;
use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Style\Shadow;
use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Shape\Chart\Series;
use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\IOFactory;

Connect(3);

global $linkid;
$queryHandler=new QueryHandler();

$query="SELECT sku,value ".
    "FROM ferrero_booker t1,booker_sku t2 ".
    "WHERE t1.skuID=t2.skuID ".
    "LIMIT 10";


$result = $queryHandler->runQuery($query,$linkid,ResultTypes::$TYPE_ARRAY);

$data=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
{
    $id=$result[$i][0];
    $data[$id]=(float)$result[$i][1];
}

$objPHPPowerPoint = new PhpPowerpoint();

$objPHPPowerPoint->getProperties()->setCreator('PHPOffice')
                              ->setLastModifiedBy('PHPPowerPoint Team')
                              ->setTitle('Sample 07 Title')
                              ->setSubject('Sample 07 Subject')
                              ->setDescription('Sample 07 Description')
                              ->setKeywords('office 2007 openxml libreoffice odt php')
                              ->setCategory('Sample Category');


$objPHPPowerPoint->removeSlideByIndex(0);


$currentSlide = createTemplatedSlide($objPHPPowerPoint);

$pie3DChart = new Pie3D();
$series = new Series('', $data);
$series->setShowSeriesName(true);
$series->getDataPointFill(0)->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)->setStartColor(new Color('FF4672A8'));
$series->getDataPointFill(1)->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)->setStartColor(new Color('FFAB4744'));
$series->getDataPointFill(2)->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)->setStartColor(new Color('FF8AA64F'));
$series->getDataPointFill(3)->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)->setStartColor(new Color('FF725990'));
$series->getDataPointFill(4)->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)->setStartColor(new Color('FF4299B0'));
$series->getDataPointFill(5)->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)->setStartColor(new Color('FFDC853E'));
$series->getDataPointFill(6)->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)->setStartColor(new Color('FF93A9CE'));
$pie3DChart->addSeries($series);


$shape = $currentSlide->createChartShape();
$shape->setName('PHPPowerPoint Daily Downloads')
      ->setResizeProportional(false)
      ->setHeight(550)
      ->setWidth(700)
      ->setOffsetX(120)
      ->setOffsetY(80);
$shape->getBorder()->setLineStyle(Border::LINE_SINGLE);
$shape->getTitle()->setText('Booker Sales');
$shape->getTitle()->getFont()->setItalic(true);
$shape->getPlotArea()->setType($pie3DChart);
$shape->getView3D()->setRotationX(90);
$shape->getView3D()->setPerspective(90);
$shape->getLegend()->getBorder()->setLineStyle(Border::LINE_SINGLE);
$shape->getLegend()->getFont()->setItalic(true);


$oWriterPPTX = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPPowerPoint, 'PowerPoint2007');
$oWriterPPTX->save("sample.pptx");

print_r($data);
```

?>

Comment: It's almost certainly possible.  Impossible to say how, though, since you haven't shown the code you're using or mentioned which version of PowerPoint you're using it with.

Comment: In PowerPoint, the UI makes it seem like the exploded pie chart is actually a different chart type. If so, then the issue may be adding that chart type in PHPPowerPoint.  I'd love to find some complete, accurate documentation on the PHPPowerPoint API.  I found one PDF, but a large amount of it was blank!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a way to do it in the code, but it's easy to modify the source.  Whether you should is another matter, but I won't touch that topic here.

The pie chart explosion is controlled by an "explosion" tag written to the xml, and this happens in the writer.  Specifically this file (on my installation/version):

```
PHPPowerPoint/src/PhpPowerpoint/Writer/PowerPoint2007/Chart.php
```

Within that file, the following lines add the explosion effect:

```
        // c:explosion
        $objWriter->startElement('c:explosion');
        $objWriter->writeAttribute('val', '20');
        $objWriter->endElement();
```

You can therefore remove the explosion by suppressing the above lines.  If you just want this attribute unconditionally gone, comment the above lines out, or delete them. If you want to extend the API, then add the relevant methods to the Pie chart class and check for the values here, conditionally executing the above lines based on those settings.

I hope this helps.